# Does anyone know how to identify an element from the android native share modal using detox framework?

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I want to identify any of the elements marked in red in the picture below, so I can do an assertion that after tapping the Share button in my app, to check that the native share modal has opened.

[image]

I tried identifying the elements by text or label, but none of this work on android

Comment: "I tried identifying the elements by text or label, but none of this work on android" - how? 

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and why.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const shareViaBluetooth = element(by.text("Bluetooth"))
await expect(shareViaBluetooth).toBeVisible()